# Elasctisearch 5.4 transport client not reachable remotely

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

My application is not able to connect to transport port 9300 remotely. But it works by localhost. When trying to connect through host or IP it doesn't work. your help is appreciated.

Settings:

```
network.host: _site_
transport.host: localhost
transport.tcp.port: 9300
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
```

when from the same machine I do telnet :9200 - works
but when doing telnet :9300 - Error:  Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I was missing parameter node discovery to be set as SingleNode. And use ip in network host. It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

`_site_` is for the private network. Use `_global_` (with great care about security, of course). I think you should only have:

```
network.host:
  - _local_
  - _global_
```

and the other lines are not needed.

Comment: Whe i use _global_ it  say org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No up-and-running global-scope (public) addresses found, got [name:lo (lo), name:eth0 (eth0), name:br-b00a12b5c415 (br-b00a12b5c415), name:br-03ee7425b4fa (br-03ee7425b4fa), name:br-359940144fb2 (br-359940144fb2), name:docker0 (docker0)]

Comment: Also if I use network ip in transport.host this fails in binding the ip and port to transport host.

Comment: Is your server connected to the internet? What happens if you `ping google.com` ?

Comment: Yeah it is connected